# Android Button Tooltip

Tags: android

[image: iOS implemenatation]

I'm new to Android and I was wondering if is possible to have an Android button element that has an embedded tooltip?  I would like to have an image on the button, that when pressed opens up a dialog/tootip overlay of some sort. So not a hover tooltip, but a clickable element that goes somewhere other than where the button click goes. If someone could guide me as to the best practice for this that would be great!

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:paddingLeft="5dip" 
    android:paddingRight="5dip">

    <Button android:id="@+id/settings_predefined_message_btn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/settings_predefined_messages"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_longbutton_witharrow" 
        style="@style/ButtonTextStyle"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip" 
        android:gravity="center" />
```

Comment: I believe you answered your own question: [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)

Comment: @Sam - but how does an Android button allow for two clickable destinations?  I'm unsure of how you would embed an image within a image.  I have an image for the button itself that will go to another screen.  The embedded image will bring up an alert, but I don't know how to embed it.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your question, could you provide the code that you have tried?  A picture of what you are trying to do might help your description as well.

Comment: @Sam - added an image from the iOS app. if you click anywher but the "i" embedded image you go to one screen, while clicking on the "i" image takes you somewhere else.  Do you know if there is an Android equivalent?

Comment: Considering tooltips usually show onHover, how are you going to show it in Android? Fingers don't hover... yet.

Comment: The picture helped. I don't know of any specific feature off-hand. The simplest approach is two buttons (or TextView & ImageButton, or two ImageButtons, etc).  Obviously you would place the smaller "i" image onto of the larger "tab" image.

Comment: @TomDignan - in my iOS impl the "i" a clickable tooltip of sorts, not hooverable

Comment: @Sam - I know how to place the "i" image next to but not on top. How is that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In response to your last comment about setting on view on top of another.)

Simple, you could use multiple LinearLayouts like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab1"
    ... />

    <TextView
        android:text="Predefined Message"
        ... />

    <ImageButton
        ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

Your LinearLayout (and maybe the TextView) should have one OnClickListener to do the main feature, the ImageButton will have a second OnClickListener for the tooltip.

**Or** you could use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) to position the tooltip ImageButton with an OnClickListener on top of the TextView with its own OnClickListener.

You can pass either of these custom view to an ActionBar to build the tabs for you, if you like. Hope that helps.

**Addition**

An (ugly!) RelativeLayout example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A long text sample"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="i"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, the specific View type doesn't matter this applies to two ImageButtons as well.

Comment: I added the screen layout above. selector_longbutton_witharrow is the image with the predefined message text on it.

Comment: Now add a second button like my updated example. (Positioning each tooltip button at the end of the text will be tricky, I recommend starting with a generous `layout_marginRight`.)