# Button on top of a Button with different Listeners

Tags: android, android-button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Button Tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506543/android-button-tooltip)

Is there any way to construct a view where a `Button` exists on top of another `Button`? Each button would need to have their own distinct `onClick` listeners.

The image below shows an iOS version of what I'm trying to achieve in Android.

The "i" portion is another image and shows a tooltip of sorts. The view is currently a `LinearLayout`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is very easy. Start with a RelativeLayout, or similar, and proceed as normal.

**Addition**

You already asked this exact same question: [Android Button Tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10506543/1267661)